# Dynamic picklist class VisualEditor.DataRow class showing error Invalid class dataerror

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to do show dependent property in app builder when component drag and drop.

**Error**

> **Invalid Class datarow at line 4** Dynamic picklist class VisualEditor.DataRow class showing error Invalid calss dataerror

**Class**

```
global class MyCustomPickList extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList{

    global override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue(){
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('red', 'RED');
        return defaultValue;
    }
    global override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DataRow value1 = new VisualEditor.DataRow('red', 'RED');
        VisualEditor.DataRow value2 = new VisualEditor.DataRow('yellow', 'YELLOW');
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows  myValues = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        myValues.addRow(value1);
        myValues.addRow(value2);
        return myValues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring '17 (API version 39.0) is when [the VisualEditor namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_VisualEditor.htm) became available.

[It is not there in Winter '17 (API version 38.0)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_VisualEditor.htm) or before.

Try [checking your Salesforce instance's API version](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?type=1&mode=1&id=000334996).